# What's the best way to make a heart & butt in LaTex?

Tags: symbols

I want to use the symbol for heart  (e.g.♥) and butt (i.e. the flipped version) in LaTex. I have the heart but I need the butt.

Two ideas occurred to me:

1. Find a butt symbol
2. If none exists, flip the heart.

I couldn't accomplish either one. Could someone either find a butt symbol or explain how to flip the heart?

Comment: **Important: I want them to match.** Who doesn't?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \newcommand{\heart}{\ensuremath\heartsuit}
   \newcommand{\butt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\heart}}

   \begin{document}

   \heart\ \butt

   \Large \heart\ \butt
   \end{document}
   ```
2. [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx,txfonts}

   \newcommand{\heart}{\ensuremath\varheartsuit}
   \newcommand{\butt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\heart}}

   \begin{document}

   \heart\ \butt

   \Large \heart\ \butt
   \end{document}
   ```